# error after login payer - "We couldn't complete your payment for you. To get your payments working again, check your account or contact us"?

Tags: paypal, checkout, subscription

i am using live credentials(app) in `localhost:5000` (Use a production WSGI server instead.)

showing this message after create subscription and login payer -

> We couldn't complete your payment for you. To get your payments
>   working again, check your account or contact us

in console showing error -

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400

agreement details :-

```
agreement_data ={

            "name": request.form.get('name'),
            "description": request.form.get('description'),
            "start_date": (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
            "plan": {
                "id": request.form.get('id')
            },
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal",
                "payer_info": {
                    "email": session.get('user_email')
                }
            }
        }
billing_agreement = BillingAgreement(agreement_data)

    if billing_agreement.create():
        print("Billing Agreement created successfully")
        for link in billing_agreement.links:
            if link.method == "REDIRECT":
                # Capture redirect url
                redirect_url = str(link.href)
                print("For approving billing agreement, redirect user to\n [%s]" % (redirect_url))
                return redirect(redirect_url)
```

**error page FULL URL** - https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9TU27402A4608321V#/checkout/genericError?code=UEFZRVJfQ0FOTk9UX01BS0VfUEFZTUVOVA%3D%3D